# Removing Duplicates of two columns in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have a select * query which gives lots of row and lots of columns of results.  I have an issue with duplicates of one column A when given the same value of another column B that I would like to only include one of.

Basically I have a column that tells me the "name" of object and another that tells me the "number".  Sometimes I have an object "name" with more than one entry for a given object "number".  I only want distinct "numbers" within a "name" but I want the query to give the entire table when this is true and not just these two columns.

```
Name Number ColumnC ColumnD

Bob    1      93      12

Bob    2      432     546

Bob    3      443     76
```

This example above is fine

```
Name Number ColumnC ColumnD

Bob    1      93      12

Bob    2      432     546

Bill   1      443     76

Bill   2      54      1856
```

This example above is fine

```
Name Number ColumnC ColumnD

Bob    1      93      12

Bob    2      432     546

Bob    2      209     17
```

This example above is not fine, I only want one of the Bob 2's.

Answer (score 1):

Try it if you are using SQL 2005 or above:

```
With ranked_records AS
(
   select *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By name, number  Order By name) [ranked] 
    from MyTable
)
select * from ranked_records
where ranked = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a Common Table Expression (CTE) and the ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTION syntax as follows:

```
WITH
  CTE AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Number ORDER BY Name, Number) AS R
    FROM
      dbo.ATable
  )      
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    CTE 
  WHERE
    R = 1
```

Comment: The only issue is what if the other columns values are different like in the example.  I don't really care which distinct row it chooses so long as its only one unique name, number

Comment: Ali beat me to my revised solution

Comment: I'll Post real quick the code I generated from this.  Can you tell me if something is missing or out of order?  I'll post as an answer that has the same code as you just gave but with the working where and order by clauses.  For some reason the query doesnt work when I execute it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the Name and number, then

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Number FROM Table1
```

If you want to know how many of each there are, then

```
SELECT Name, Number, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Name, Number
```

Comment: The only issue is what if the other columns values are different like in the example.  I don't really care which distinct row it chooses so long as its only one unique name, number

Comment: How are you going to determine which values in the other columns you want to display?  Do both have to be from the same row?  ie, would (Bob,2,432,17) be an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 0):

WITH

CTE AS

(

```
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Plant, BatchNumber ORDER BY Plant, BatchNumber) AS R
FROM dbo.StatisticalReports WHERE dbo.StatisticalReports. \!"FermBatchStartTime\!" >= DATEADD(d,-90, getdate())
```

)

SELECT

```
*
```

FROM

```
CTE
```

WHERE

```
R = 1
```

ORDER BY dbo.StatisticalReports.Plant, dbo.StatisticalReports.FermBatchStartTime

Comment: Do you get an error message? And what does the part \!"FermBatchStartTime\!" mean. Perhaps you should show me the table structure.